# Cant declare a list as a global variable?

Tags: c#, console-application

```
class Program
{
    List<int> ages = new List<int>();
```

Cant be access inside of other methods, please tell me why?
I get error message cs0120 "A object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property 'program.ages'"

Thanks

Comment: How are you *trying* to access it?  The error you describe is pointing to a line of code you're not showing.  Provide a *complete* and *minimal* example.

Answer (score 2):

Change your list declaration `static` and `public`

```
class Program
{
   public static List<int> ages = new List<int>();

   // other method and stuff you want
}
```